# Changing an order of columns below marged (cell) columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, spreadsheet, export-to-excel

I need to change order of columns inside of years. It needs to be ['profit', 'loss', 'other', 'status', 'index']. But I can not make it because i have a row above which marks a year and I need to keep this. Usual solutions is not working! This is my code but it won't work.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_excel('products2.xlsx', index_col=[0])

df.columns = df.columns.str.split('_', expand=True)

new_data = df.stack(0)
new_data1 = new_data.eval('status = profit - loss + other')
new_data2 = new_data1.eval('index = (profit / status) / (loss / status)')
# if i put here an order, it will work temperoraly, until output and in the end I won't get an order that i want
order = new_data2.reindex(columns=['profit', 'loss', 'other', 'status', 'index'])
output = new_data2.unstack(1).swaplevel(0,1, axis=1).sort_index(axis=1)
# i should probably put it here, but it destroy a whole table
output.to_excel('output_products.xlsx')
```

This is a [Dropbox link](https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/qlpt24tavurb7olbaaq07/products2.xlsx?dl=0&rlkey=6st445ssszdyqswhbzdkbqlyj) of excel document.

Comment: Please update your post with your expect output please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your problem correctly you need to change the order of the columns, but just according to the level 1 of columns. If that is the case, you could try reindex like this:

```
output = output.reindex(columns=['profit', 'loss', 'other', 'status', 'index'], level=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

As you have **MultiIndex** and your desired order of level 1 column index is not in alphabetical order (neither ascending nor descending), you have to set level1 column index as a **Categorical Index** by [`MultiIndex.set_levels`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.set_levels.html) and [`pd.CategoricalIndex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.CategoricalIndex.html).  Then, you can `sort_index` on columns to obtain the required column order:

```
df.columns = df.columns.set_levels(pd.CategoricalIndex(df.columns.levels[1], 
                                   categories=['profit', 'loss', 'other', 'status', 'index'], ordered=True), 
             level=1)

df = df.sort_index(axis=1)
```

### Demo

**Data Input**

As your sample Excel in Dropbox has only the 3 columns `profit`, `loss`, `other` and is missing the 2 columns `status` and `index`, I have tried to add the 2 missing columns, as follows:

```
print(df)

           2017_index 2017_status  2017_profit  2017_loss  2017_other  2018_index 2018_status  2018_profit  2018_loss  2018_other  2019_index 2019_status  2019_profit  2019_loss  2019_other  2020_index 2020_status  2020_profit  2020_loss  2020_other
companies                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
company1            1       Ready         3000        500        3000           1       Ready         3500       2000        5000           1       Ready         3000       3000        4000           1       Ready         4400       3000        4000
company2            2       Ready         2900        600        2800           2       Ready         3300       1400        3400           2       Ready         3000       2000         300           2       Ready         3200       1700         500
company3            3       Ready         3100        900        3200           3       Ready         2900       2000        2400           3       Ready         3500        400        2000           3       Ready         5000       3100        1500
company4            4       Ready         2000       2000        3100           4       Ready         4100       1800         400           4       Ready         3000       3000        1900           4       Ready         4400       2200        1300
company5            5       Ready         1400        100         500           5       Ready         2000       3000        1300           5       Ready         2500        800        2000           5       Ready         3000       1200        1700
company6            6       Ready         2000        800         800           6       Ready         1500       2000        4000           6       Ready         2000        600        2000           6       Ready         3000       3400        3600
company7            7       Ready         2700       1500        1900           7       Ready         3000       2000        4400           7       Ready         2000       5000        3000           7       Ready         2000       3500        1200
company8            8       Ready         1300       1100        3000           8       Ready         1600       1800        3200           8       Ready         3000       2000         200           8       Ready         2700       2000        1400
```

Then, after your code to split column index into **MultiIndex** by the code:

```
df.columns = df.columns.str.split('_', expand=True)
```

we get:

```
print(df)

          2017                            2018                            2019                            2020                          
          index status profit  loss other index status profit  loss other index status profit  loss other index status profit  loss other
companies                                                                                                                                
company1      1  Ready   3000   500  3000     1  Ready   3500  2000  5000     1  Ready   3000  3000  4000     1  Ready   4400  3000  4000
company2      2  Ready   2900   600  2800     2  Ready   3300  1400  3400     2  Ready   3000  2000   300     2  Ready   3200  1700   500
company3      3  Ready   3100   900  3200     3  Ready   2900  2000  2400     3  Ready   3500   400  2000     3  Ready   5000  3100  1500
company4      4  Ready   2000  2000  3100     4  Ready   4100  1800   400     4  Ready   3000  3000  1900     4  Ready   4400  2200  1300
company5      5  Ready   1400   100   500     5  Ready   2000  3000  1300     5  Ready   2500   800  2000     5  Ready   3000  1200  1700
company6      6  Ready   2000   800   800     6  Ready   1500  2000  4000     6  Ready   2000   600  2000     6  Ready   3000  3400  3600
company7      7  Ready   2700  1500  1900     7  Ready   3000  2000  4400     7  Ready   2000  5000  3000     7  Ready   2000  3500  1200
company8      8  Ready   1300  1100  3000     8  Ready   1600  1800  3200     8  Ready   3000  2000   200     8  Ready   2700  2000  1400
```

**Run the solution codes:**

```
df.columns = df.columns.set_levels(pd.CategoricalIndex(df.columns.levels[1], 
                                   categories=['profit', 'loss', 'other', 'status', 'index'], ordered=True), 
             level=1)

df = df.sort_index(axis=1)
```

**Result:**

```
print(df)

          2017                            2018                            2019                            2020                         
          profit  loss other status index profit  loss other status index profit  loss other status index profit  loss other status index
companies                                                                                                                                
company1    3000   500  3000  Ready     1   3500  2000  5000  Ready     1   3000  3000  4000  Ready     1   4400  3000  4000  Ready     1
company2    2900   600  2800  Ready     2   3300  1400  3400  Ready     2   3000  2000   300  Ready     2   3200  1700   500  Ready     2
company3    3100   900  3200  Ready     3   2900  2000  2400  Ready     3   3500   400  2000  Ready     3   5000  3100  1500  Ready     3
company4    2000  2000  3100  Ready     4   4100  1800   400  Ready     4   3000  3000  1900  Ready     4   4400  2200  1300  Ready     4
company5    1400   100   500  Ready     5   2000  3000  1300  Ready     5   2500   800  2000  Ready     5   3000  1200  1700  Ready     5
company6    2000   800   800  Ready     6   1500  2000  4000  Ready     6   2000   600  2000  Ready     6   3000  3400  3600  Ready     6
company7    2700  1500  1900  Ready     7   3000  2000  4400  Ready     7   2000  5000  3000  Ready     7   2000  3500  1200  Ready     7
company8    1300  1100  3000  Ready     8   1600  1800  3200  Ready     8   3000  2000   200  Ready     8   2700  2000  1400  Ready     8
```